# Put a Composition effect behind a control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I've applied a shadow effect on a simple TextBlock control, but I've a problem : the shadow is in front of the Textblock and I don't know how to put the shadow behind the TextBlock. Do you have the solution for this problem ?
There is the code that creates the DropShadow effect:

```
public void SetupSimpleTextShadow(TextBlock shadowTarget)
    {
        Visual hostVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(shadowTarget);
        Compositor compositor = hostVisual.Compositor;

        DropShadow dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
        dropShadow.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 50, 50);
        dropShadow.BlurRadius = 7f;
        dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(5f, 5f, 0f);
        dropShadow.Opacity = 0.9f;
        dropShadow.Mask = shadowTarget.GetAlphaMask(); 

        SpriteVisual shadowVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        shadowVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(shadowTarget, shadowVisual);

        ExpressionAnimation bindSizeAnimation = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("hostVisual.Size");
        bindSizeAnimation.SetReferenceParameter("hostVisual", hostVisual);

        shadowVisual.StartAnimation("Size", bindSizeAnimation);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use XPShadow.The sample link is https://github.com/brookshi/XPShadow.

Finding the XPShadow in Nuget and download it.

Writing the ref NameSpace :`xmlns:xp="using:XP"`

In the code that you want the control have shadow,you can use the control in xp:Shadow.

```
              <xp:Shadow CornerRadius="2"
                           IsCached="True"
                           Z_Depth="2">
                         <Control/>
              </xp:Shadow>
```